# cljs.closure is not found

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datomic

I have a `build.boot` config like this:

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src/dev_cljs" "src/cljs"}
 :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0-alpha14"]
                 [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5561"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.542"]
                 [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.10"]])

(deftask cider
  []
  (require 'boot.repl)
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/*default-dependencies*)
         concat '[[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.15.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                  [refactor-nrepl "2.3.0-SNAPSHOT"]])
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/*default-middleware*)
         concat '[cider.nrepl/cider-middleware
                  refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor])
  identity)
```

And in `myproject.fighwheel` on "src/dev_cljs" I'm requiring `[figwheel-sidecar.repl :as fw]` and it throws with an error "`cljs.closure` is not found" and this doesn't throw if I remove the dependency on `[com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5561"]`. Can someone help me work around this?

Thinking this is a dependency conflict, I use `boot show -p` and got a bunch of results I don't know how to interpret it:

```
[!] args4j
    ✔ 2.33
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 2.0.26
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] commons-codec
    ✘ 1.6
      figwheel-sidecar
    ✔ 1.5
      com.datomic/datomic-free
[!] com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305
    ✔ 3.0.1
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 1.3.9
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] com.google.code.gson/gson
    ✔ 2.7
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 2.2.4
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] com.google.guava/guava
    ✘ 20.0
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 19.0
      figwheel-sidecar
    ✔ 18.0
      com.datomic/datomic-free
[!] com.google.javascript/closure-compiler-externs
    ✔ v20170423
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ v20160315
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java
    ✔ 3.0.2
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 2.5.0
      figwheel-sidecar
[✔] org.clojure/clojure
    ✔ 1.9.0-alpha14
      org.clojure/clojure
    ✘ 1.8.0
      figwheel-sidecar
      com.datomic/datomic-free
      org.clojure/clojurescript
[✔] org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✔ 1.9.542
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 1.8.51
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] org.clojure/google-closure-library
    ✔ 0.0-20160609-f42b4a24
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 0.0-20151016-61277aea
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] org.clojure/google-closure-library-third-party
    ✔ 0.0-20160609-f42b4a24
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 0.0-20151016-61277aea
      figwheel-sidecar
[!] org.clojure/tools.reader
    ✔ 1.0.0-beta3
      org.clojure/clojurescript
    ✘ 1.0.0-beta1
      figwheel-sidecar
```

Comment: It's the Guava dep. You'll need a newer one for CLJS. Don't use datomic + CLJS in the same JVM IMO.